# android 2D bitmap drawing

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, drawing

Can any1 tell me why I cant add a bitmap onto my surfaceView like this:

```
    steering = new Steering(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), getWidth()-50,getHeight()-50);
```

if I use integers instead of the "getHeight()"-method, the bitmap is added just fine. But since I want this game to run on more then 1 phone without looking weird I want to add it using those 2 methods.

can any1 help?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where exactly you are adding that line? if its on your `onCreate` then it wouldnt display you the image since the method `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` would return 0. So to paint it you have to wait until the system have actually created the view.
To test that you are actually receiving a value try changing the code you actually have for something like this:

```
final int width = getWidth();
final int height = getHeight();
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
steering = new Steering(bitmap, width-50,height-50);
```

and add a breakpoint to the steering line and debugg it. If you are getting 0 in the width and height then you will have to wait for the view to draw.

***Edit:***
on your `Activity`/`Fragment` you can add a tree observer like this:

```
 myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    //Do something here since now you have the width and height of your view
                }
            });
```

Here is a small example on how you would do it in your classes:

***My Steering Class:***

```
public class Steering {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;

    public Steering(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height) {
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        this.mWidth = width;
        this.mHeight = height;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        //reescaling from anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621
        final int imageWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        final int imageHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        // calculate the scale -
        float scaleWidth = ((float) mWidth) / imageWidth;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) mHeight) / imageHeight;
        // createa matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, matrix, true);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

}
```

***My Activity***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyView mView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.viewid);
        OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                final int width = mView.getWidth();
                final int height = mView.getHeight();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android);
                //image from anddev
                final Steering steering = new Steering(bitmap, width-50,height-50);
                mView.setObject(steering);
            }
        };
        mView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }

}
```

**and my View Class**

```
public class MyView extends View{

    Steering steering = null;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setObject(Steering steering){
        this.steering = steering;
    }

    final Paint paint = new Paint();

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        if(steering!=null){
            canvas.drawBitmap(steering.getBitmap(), 0, 0, paint);
        }
        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```

You can use this for a normal view or a surfaceView, either way works.
Sorry if the answer is a bit too long :P

Comment: so there is no way to att something using those methods in the constructor?

Comment: no, but in your activity you can use the treeobserver.. I just updated my answer for you :)

Comment: thank you for helping but cant get that one to work either, im new to android-programming so. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: just add a setMethod on your class that extends View. I'm going to try to edit my answer as soon as posible to show you an example.

Comment: wow, thank you so much, much more then I expected, this will rly help :)